# UK: How to *leave* self select stock and shares ISA (without selling the shares)?

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, isa

I have decided I no longer wish to pick my own shares (too much effort) but want to keep those I already have in ISAs from previous years.  Thus I think I need some kind of holding service for my existing shares in their ISAs, that maintains their tax free status, but doesn't use up my future ISA allowance.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Open a share dealing account and transfer you shares(but they do charge for inactivity), check out equiniti as they offer shareholding services.

Comment: What do you mean by "future ISA allowance"? The ISA allowance is per tax year, and so resets every April, regardless of how much you put in in a previous year.

Comment: "Future ISA allowances" then, sorry

Comment: @DumbCoder So will a standard (non-ISA) sharedealing account maintain the ISA status of my existing shares as they were originally bought in an ISA?

Comment: I am not so sure on that. I would call a provider to confirm with them. Call one of the share dealing providers and get first hand information.

Comment: @SideshowBob, I think you are missing what Steve Melnikoff is trying to say. You can leave your existing ISA deposits where they are, forever and day, without having any impact on future ISA deposits. The ISA allowance is a yearly limit on the amount of new money put into ISAs from outside, so each year you can put a new chunk into ISAs (whether stocks and shares, cash or whatever) regardless of what you hold from previous years.

Comment: Yup; what Vicky said. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your existing shares in their existing ISA(s) do not in any way impact on your future ISA allowances.

The only thing that uses up your ISA allowance is you paying new cash into an ISA account.

So you can leave your existing shares in their existing ISA(s) and simply open new ISA(s) for future contributions which suit your current plans.